# How to get (Android) views's layout values from shell?

Tags: android, shell

For a Test automation task I'm trying to do the following:
- Determine the screen positioning of a specific control. 
- With the position click on it.
- If moving to other activity, finding the location of the next control on the list/script.

The set of operations is that. Basically to do this, I'm trying to, from a shell script have access to the values that hierarchyviewer would provide me on a GUI.

So far I've had a look at jwdp and I can use jdb to attach to my app's instance and I see the threads. However I can't deeper than seeing threads, thread groups and the loaded classes.

Anyone has a suggestion on how /whether this can be done ?

Comment: If you are trying to duplicate capability that DDMS has, then you could examine the source code of DDMS...

Comment: I see now that the that DDMS approach might be too cumbersome, and not giving me the info I need. I want to know the absolute position of a control on the screen. Looking the output of hierarchy viewer it only provides relative positions of elements on the views they are placed. I need absolute positions, so that I can call 'input tap' to click on them.